# How do i save specific lines in a textfile to specific arrays?

Tags: c#

**The text file is as follows**

```
City Name:           Timber
Date:                24/23/2020
Maximum Temperature: 34°C
Minimum Temperature: 20°C
Precipitation:       30%
Humidity:            40%
Wind Speed:          15km\h
 
City Name:           Timber
Date:                24/24/2020
Maximum Temperature: 32°C
Minimum Temperature: 22°C
Precipitation:       28%
Humidity:            38%
Wind Speed:          13km\h
 
City Name:           yellow
Date:                24/23/2020
Maximum Temperature: 25°C
Minimum Temperature: 16°C
Precipitation:       23%
Humidity:            21%
Wind Speed:          10km\h
```

I Would like to save the information into 7 different arrays as follows :

where the line starts with `City Name:`  store those line into an array and count the entry.

where the line starts with `Date:` store those lines into an array and count the entry.

Etc.....

Comment: Step 1) Read file, Step 2) `foreach` loop, Step 3) `If` statements, Step 4) lunch

Comment: Why `7` arrays? Why not a *single* array of *custom* classes?

Comment: okay thanks do you know how the code for the foreach should look, i think i need to use a where clause in it but dont quite know how?

Comment: Which specific part of the problem are you struggling with? If you need help on `foreach` search for that. If you need to know how to read a file search for that. If you need help parsing your file search for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you'll use [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netcore-3.1) for reading the file,
and you can do something like:

```
using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(path))
{
     string line = stream.ReadLine();
     if (line.StartWith("City Name:"))
     {
          citiesArray.Add(string.Substring("City Name:".Length);
     }
}
```

In addition:

1. I recommend you to hold the const strings "City Name: ",  "Date: ", etc
   in `readonly string` variables in the class that responsible for reading this file.
2. I recommend you to not use array, but instead use `List<string>` which is implementing array in the back of it, but the using interface with this class is more Object-Oriented-friendly

Answer (score 0):

This does it.

```
public static string[] GetArray(string txt, string type){
    string[] lines = txt.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split('\n');
    List<string> lns = new List<string>();
    
    for (int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
        if (lines[i].Length > type.Length && lines[i].ToLower().Substring(0, type.Length).Equals(type.ToLower()))
            lns.Add (lines[i].Substring(21));
        
    return lns.ToArray();
}
```

Eg. Running `GetArray(txt, "City Name");` now Returns this array:

```
Timber
Timber
yellow
```

Comment: thanks Maor and Mereb, that is more and less what i was looking for.